# Searching text with regex which is starting with specific pattern

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript

I am searching the word inside the text using specific keyword.

```
const matchHashtags = /(#\w+) ?/g;
const text ="this is #sample tag and other #another tag";
while ((hashtag = matchHashtags.exec(text))) {
      alert(hashtag);
}
```

As in above, we are searching using the word starting with # and it is working fine. But with the below code, I am searching for the text starting with "iphone~".

```
const matchHashtags2 = /(^|\s)\iphone~(\w+)/g;
const text2 ="I have iphone~seven~new and iphone~seven~ old phones";
while ((hashtag2 = matchHashtags2.exec(text2))) {
      alert(hashtag2);
}
```

I am expecting this to search for iphone~seven i.e to include next word after iphone~. But this query is returning output as 3 values:  "iphone~seven, ,seven".

https://jsfiddle.net/gecj54a3/1/

Please assist in resolving the issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What´s wrong with `const matchHashtags2 = /(iphone~\w+) ?/g;`?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var text2 = 'I have iphone~seven~new and iphone~seven~old phones';
var myArray2 = text2.split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < myArray2.length; i++){
    if(myArray2[i].includes('iphone')){
        alert(myArray2[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const matchHashtags2 = /(^|\s)\iphone~(\w+)/g;
const text2 ="I have iphone~seven~new and iphone~seven~ old phones";
while ((hashtag2 = matchHashtags2.exec(text2))) {
      alert(hashtag2[2]); // hashtag2 is an array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that result in the alert is because you are using a capture group.

Also note that in your code you don't need the extra set of parenthesis for the while loop, and in the pattern you don't have to escape `\i` to match an `i` char.

If you use `(^|\s)` and there is a leading space, it will be part of the match. What you can do is make that part a non capture group, and use a capture group for the part that you are interested in.

Then use console.log to see the group 1 value.

```js
const matchHashtags2 = /(?:^|\s)(iphone~\w+)/g;
const text2 = "I have iphone~seven~new and iphone~seven~ old phones";
let hashtag2;
while (hashtag2 = matchHashtags2.exec(text2)) {
  console.log(hashtag2[1]);
}
```

Or you can write the code using [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) without a capture group and still with the global flag `/g` preceded with a word boundary `\b` if that is also acceptable for the matches.

```js
const matchHashtags2 = /\biphone~\w+/g;
const text2 = "I have iphone~seven~new and iphone~seven~ old phones";
console.log(text2.match(matchHashtags2));
```